# Laravel builder conditional clauses that can return more than 1 condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql

I want to add some extra clauses to my query only when I get a specific request

I can do it with https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses

```
    ->when($markeplace_id !=0, function ($query) use ($marketplace_id){
       return $query->join('seller b', 'a.seller_id', '=', 'b.seller_id')
    });

    ->when($markeplace_id !=0, function ($query) use ($marketplace_id){
       return $query->join('marketplaces as c', 'c.marketplace_id', '=', 'b.marketplace_id')
    });
    ->when($markeplace_id !=0, function ($query) use ($marketplace_id){
       return $query->where('c.marketplace_id','=',$marketplace_id)
    });
```

Conditional-clauses only returns 1 clause. But I have 3. Should I use when 3 times or can I just bundle them in to 1 when ?

```
    ->join('sellers as b', 'a.seller_id', '=', 'b.seller_id')
    ->join('marketplaces as c', 'c.marketplace_id', '=', 'b.marketplace_id')
    ->where('c.marketplace_id','=',$marketplace_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
->when($markeplace_id !=0, function ($query) use ($marketplace_id){
   $query->join('seller b', 'a.seller_id', '=', 'b.seller_id');
   $query->join('marketplaces as c', 'c.marketplace_id', '=', 'b.marketplace_id');
   return $query->where('c.marketplace_id','=',$marketplace_id);
});
```

I didn't tested it.Let me know if not works

Comment: Logically it wouldn't work, since others are not returned.

Comment: try return $query->join('seller b', 'a.seller_id', '=', 'b.seller_id')->join('marketplaces as c', 'c.marketplace_id', '=', 'b.marketplace_id')->where('c.marketplace_id','=',$marketplace_id);

Comment: @SNaRe: It does work. Since `$query` is an object, `return $query;` would also work.